# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

BookStore is the parent component and the SearchBooks is the child component. It compiles well but I get a runtime error that the child component is not resolved.

BookStore.tsx (parent component)

```
import { SearchBooks, SearchParameters } from 'ClientApp/components/SearchBooks';
...
export class BookStore extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> 
...
<SearchBooks searchForBooks={this.searchForBooks} />
```

SearchBooks.tsx

```
export class SearchBooks extends React.Component<IBookSearchProps> 
...
```

Routes.tsx

```
...
<Route path='/bookStore' component={BookStore} />
```

File Tree:

[image: File tree]

Error:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/components/BookStore.tsx
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ClientApp/components/SearchBooks' in '...\ClientApp\components'
>        @ ./ClientApp/components/BookStore.tsx 12:0-63
>        @ ./ClientApp/routes.tsx
>        @ ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
>        @ multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.tsx

Comment: howd you import?

Comment: @Omar updated the code

Comment: try `import { SearchBooks, SearchParameters } from './components/SearchBooks';`

Comment: @Omar This gives the error that it cannot find module.

Comment: can you show your file tree

Comment: @Omar I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { SearchBooks, SearchParameters } from './SearchBooks';
```

Same directory components and the file is SearchBooks.

Comment: This too gave me an error, I added the one that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: yeah added /components unnecessarily, but i was right about same directory and file being SearchBooks.